# MapKit MKMarkerAnnotationView subtitleVisibility in iOS 12

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mapkitannotation

In an `MKMarkerAnnotationView`, when I set

```
self.titleVisibility = .visible
self.subtitleVisibility = .visible
```

then title and subtitle are rendered below the marker.

when I set

```
self.titleVisibility = .adaptive
self.subtitleVisibility = .adaptive
```

then it appears that the subtitle is never rendered below a marker:

[image]

My understanding is that adaptive means, that the subtitle is rendered if there is enough space.
This is a salt lake, there is nothing around it that should prevent rendering the subtitle "SALT LAKE".

Do I miss something? What else could prevent the subtitle from being rendered?

I don't want to force rendering, because adaptive is there for a reason and sometimes a map is too crowded to render subtitles.